# Does Perl6 (a.k.a Raku) support something equivalent to Perl5's __DATA__ and __END__ sections?

Tags: perl, raku, rakudo

Does perl6/Rakudo have something equivalent to perl5's `__DATA__` or `__END__` sections?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quote [S26](http://zag.ru/perl6-pod/S26.html#146202336):

> Named Perldoc blocks whose typename is
>   DATA are the Perl 6 equivalent of the
>   Perl 5 `__DATA__` section. The
>   difference is that =DATA blocks are
>   just regular Pod blocks and may appear
>   anywhere within a source file, and as
>   many times as required. [Synopsis 2](http://perlcabal.org/syn/S02.html)
>   describes the new Perl 6 interface for
>   inline data.

In theory you should be able to do something like this (somebody please fix the syntax if it’s off):

```
use v6;

=begin DATA
Foo
=end DATA

say @=DATA;
```

[In practice it seems](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=854416) that Rakudo does not support that, yet.

Comment: Unfortunately Rakudo doesn't implement them yet.

Answer (score 13):

To carefully selectively quote the current [S02](http://design.perl6.org/S02.html#Double-underscore_forms) design document:

> There is no longer any special DATA stream--any Pod block in the
>   current file can be accessed via a Pod object ...
>
> You have to split [Pod block] contents into lines yourself.
>
> [Speculative] It may also be possible to treat a Pod object as an
>   IO::Handle, to read the Pod information line-by-line (like the DATA
>   filehandle in Perl 5, but for any Pod block).

So, instead of the single **DATA** section per file which you access by reading a filehandle, you define any number of Pod blocks in your script file; they're stored in the `$=pod` variable at compile time; you read from that variable; and the ones called 'data' are the equivalents of Perl 5's **DATA**.

This works today. I'll show that in a moment. But first I need to talk about stuff that does not work today.

The quoting above was highly selective. The elided text talked about P6 automatically creating a variable with a name of the form `$=foo` corresponding to Pod blocks with the name 'foo'. This is a general still unimplemented feature of Pod blocks, not just data blocks.

The "data block" section of the Pod design doc [S26](http://design.perl6.org/S26.html#Data_blocks) talks about data blocks doing some fancier stuff than plain old Pod blocks. This has not yet been implemented either.

So, now let's move on to what can be done today:

```
=foo This is a Pod block. A single line one. This Pod block's name is 'foo'.

=begin qux
This is another syntax for defining a Pod block.
It allows for multi line content.
This block's name is 'qux'.
=end qux

=data A data block -- a Pod block with the name 'data'.

# Data blocks are P6's version of P5's __DATA__.
# But you can have multiple data blocks:

=begin data
Another data block.
This time a multi line one.
=end data

$=pod.grep(*.name eq 'data').map(*.contents[0].contents.say);
```

This prints:

```
A data block -- a Pod block with the name 'data'.
Another data block. This time a multi line one.
```

So, it sorta works. But it clearly needs a lot more sugar.

By the way, if the last FP style line didn't make sense, here's an imperative equivalent:

```
for @$=pod {
  if .name eq 'data' {
    say .contents[0].contents
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

As a work-around until this gets fully implemented, you can use heredocs.

```
for data().lines -> $line {
    put $line;
}

sub data {
    return q:to/END/;
           Foo, bar, baz
           1, 2, 3
           END
}
```

Outputs

> ```
> Foo, bar, baz
> 1, 2, 3
> ```

Answer (score 4):

To get an array of data, while putting the data at the bottom of the program to help with readability, here is an variation of @Christopher Bottoms answer:

```
my @txts = data();
dd @txts;
# this works too
my %stuff = hashdata();
dd %stuff;

# a lot of lines

sub data() {
    return ( q:to/LINE1/,
        Phasellus dictum, nunc id vestibulum rhoncus, mauris massa tempus nibh, 
        nec tincidunt nisi tellus et arcu. Phasellus vulputate consectetur
        vulputate. Quisque viverra commodo velit ac tincidunt. Nulla et est sem.
        Mauris gravida, nulla rutrum pharetra dapibus, eros velit feugiat nibh,
        nec iaculis purus urna ut diam. Praesent molestie felis a turpis gravida
        placerat. Duis sagittis pulvinar risus non aliquet. Nunc quis purus
        tempor, mattis nunc eu, porta ligula. Suspendisse dictum sit amet urna
        dapibus suscipit.  
        LINE1  
        q:to/LINE2/,  
        Praesent molestie felis a turpis gravida
        placerat. Duis sagittis pulvinar risus non aliquet. Nunc quis purus
        tempor, mattis nunc eu, porta ligula. Suspendisse dictum sit amet urna
        dapibus suscipit.
        LINE2
        q:to/LINE3/);
        Quisque viverra commodo velit ac tincidunt. Nulla et est sem.
        Mauris gravida, nulla rutrum pharetra dapibus, eros velit feugiat nibh,
        nec iaculis purus urna ut diam. Praesent molestie felis a turpis gravida
        placerat.
        LINE3
}

sub hashdata() { # a hash works too.
      return ( 'p' => q:to/PDATA/,
        Some multiline data
        in some lines
        PDATA

        'q' => q:to/QDATA/,
           More data in 
           multiple lines
           QDATA

         'r' => q:to/RDATA/
              Note that indentation depends on the position of the 
              ending token.
              Also, the punctuation following the regex is the punctuation
              following the expression. So a comma after each of the 
              p and q, but not needed after the r
              RDATA
         )
}
```

Comment: Three heredocs in one array. Nice! Thanks for bringing this up. It reminds me of something similar I've done with hashes (trying to emulate [Data::Section](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Section) from Perl 5).

Answer (score 1):

**YES.**

According to this [2023 perl6.users](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl6.users/2023/06/msg10997.html) email conversation, you end your program/document with:

`=finish`

Then: *"Anything after `=finish` is put in string that can be pulled into a Raku program with `$=finish` (also undocumented).*"

So you can reference the string (within the body of your program) using:

`$=finish`

---

That link further elaborates:

1. *"`=finish` was introduced instead of Perl's `__DATA__`."*
2. *"`=finish` is an undocumented part of the POD6 specification ... . It will be documented soon."*

---

https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl6.users/2023/06/msg10997.html